# Browser refresh resets gulp watch scss compile

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch

Basically, I run gulp watch, I change some scss code and hit save, then changes are applied to the site but when I refresh the page the changes are lost, So I have to hit save again in my code editor.

Anyone recognize this? Thing is the 'refresh' didnt lose changes scss changes on my older computer, so maybe I have forgotten something, Thanks.

Comment: add your gulpfile.js

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you had enabled css injection before.
There it is not "refreshing" the page to show your new changes but injects the new css to the browser.

But this does not really explain - why changes are lost after refresh.